# Функция выделения ссылок в текста. Помощь с видом google.ru

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Есть функция, которая выделяет ссылки в тексте. Ссылки вида: http://google.ru и www.google.ru выделяются успешно, а вот google.ru не выделяются. То есть нужно третье регуярное выражение по замене ссылок вида google.ru

```
function link_it($text) { // преобразование текста в ссылку
 $text = preg_replace('/(http:\/\/([\w\d\.\?\&\#\;\:\+\-\=\%\/]+))/i', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $text);
 $text = preg_replace('/(www.([a-zA-Z_0-9\.\?\&\#\;\:\+\-\=\%\/]*))/i', '<a href="http://$1">$1</a>', $text);

 return($text);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте это:

```
/(([a-z]+:\/\/)?(?:[a-zа-я0-9@:_-]+\.)+[a-zа-я0-9]{2,4}(?(2)|\/).*?)([-.,:]?(?:\\s|\$))/is
```

Включает:
- все мыслимые и не мыслимые протоколы, а также их отсутствие.
- любое количество субдоменов.
- кириллицу в имени сайта, что актуально в наше время для РФ.
- ссылка оканчивается на пробел или где конец строки.
- ссылка обязательно содержит слэш, иначе помимо google.ru выражение будет ловить и system.time.getLocalTime()
Использование:

```
$text=<<<HEREDOC
http://Google.com/test
Google.com
Google.com/test
http://Google.com
HEREDOC;

echo preg_replace("/(([a-z]+:\/\/)?(?:[a-zа-я0-9@:_-]+\.)+[a-zа-я0-9]{2,4}(?(2)|\/).*?)([-.,:]?(?:\\s|\$))/is",'<b>$1</b>$3', $text);
```

Результат:

> **http://Google.com/test**
> Google.com
> **Google.com/test**
> **http://Google.com**

Comment: хм. но ведь в реальной жизни никто не пишет слеш в конце ссылки, правда? так что ловить надо, судя по всему, по списку TLD.

Comment: Обычно пишут :) Большинство ссылок ведут не на корень сайта, а на какую-то страницу.  
Если без слэша, то нужен обязательно протокол тогда, иначе будет находить любые слова написанные слитно через точку.  
Усложню это выражение чуть позже и обновлю ответ.

Comment: @ReinRaus, тогда подожду новое выражение :))

Comment: Обновил. Теперь можно без слэша, если есть протокол.

Comment: @ReinRaus, а как же www.google.com? Как я понял, google.com тоже не распознает?

Comment: Ну и получаем xss Google.com/"onclick="alert()

Comment: Как я уже говорил это не красиво выделять такие адреса. Например будет выделено:  

    import apache.www.SimpleHttp.node
    apache.www.SimpleHttp.createSimpleServer("string");
В общем стоит это выделять или нет зависит от контента на сайте. Если сайт не для обмена кусками кода, то можно выделять.

Comment: Следить за xss в условии не было :)  
А вообще можно усложнять выражение до бесконечности. Нет идеального выражения для таких задач.