# Подсветка ссылок в тексте функцией php

Tags: php

Нужно в тексте $text найти ссылки, которые могут быть в разных форматах и сделать их реальными ссылками, т.е. добавить

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">http://google.com</a>
```

Есть [такой пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/167531/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC-google-ru)

Но он не работает, если текст со ссылкой внутри заканчивается тегом, например:

```
<p>Вот так выглядит ссылка на сайт <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">http://google.com</a></p>
```

В этом случае ссылка получается с окончанием

```
<p>Вот так выглядит ссылка на сайт <a href="http://google.com/%3C/p%3E">http://google.com</a></p>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как доработать скрипт, чтобы он корректно такие тексты обрабатывал.

Вот еще пример функции, но она отрабатывается также, заканчивается тегом P:

```
return preg_replace_callback(
'{
  (?:
    (\w+://)          # протокол с двумя слэшами
    |                 # - или -
    www\.             # просто начинается на www
  )
  [\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*   # имя хоста
  \S*                 # URI (но БЕЗ кавычек)
  (?:                 # последний символ должен быть...
      (?<! [[:punct:]] )  # НЕ пунктуацией
    | (?<= [-/&+*]     )  # но допустимо окончание на -/&+*
  )
}xi',
"hrefCallback",
$text
```

);

Нужно поправить одну из этих функций или обе или может есть более простой вариант?

Comment: Сколько раз говорено - не используйте регулярки с HTML!

Comment: Как тогда делать подсветку ссылок?

Comment: Вообще `html` можно управлять через `DOMDocument` например. Но если используется текстуальная ссылка, то без регулярки никак.

Answer (score 0):

Проверяйте позицию подстроки, в которой перед протоколом `http` отсутствует атрибут `href="`. Таким образом существующие ссылки не будут модифицированы:

```
$str = '
    какой-то текст и <a href="http://site.com">Ссылка</a>
    и ещё ссылка https://google.com
';

$patt = '~(?<!href=")https?://\S+~';
$repl = '<a href="$0" target="_blank">$0</a>';

echo preg_replace($patt, $repl, $str);
```